# how to send data in quickbooks as a journal entries from the rake task of rails 6 app

Tags: task, rake, ruby-on-rails-6, quickbooks

i was trying to integrate quickbooks with my rails 6 app in which i need to run the rake task and it will send data to quickbooks as a journal entries.  But all the articles i found was to connect with intuite from frontend page of ruby.
Please help anyone tha i have to send integrate quickbooks in such a way that i just run the rake task and it will insert data into quickbooks.
any article or suggestion?

I read a lot of articles but in every article it says you need to connect to quickbooks from the frontend through intuit button

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LucianaOliveira first of all i was trying to configure the oauth configuration in which i got the issue of redirect_url which i resolved by implementing api and map the redirect_url with my api and store the data in database in my api. So, when authentication is done. How can i insert a journal entry from the rake test directly in quickbooks without using frontend.

Comment: Hi, Jahangeer ! I think you want to  insert a journal entry from the rake test directly in quickbooks using the command lines? If you clarify once more about it, your question could be answer faster.

Comment: yes exactly @LucianaOliveira